# "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end"

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I put together this script based on this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWI1PIvy4A8).

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/sby/jjj/"

data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

puts data.at_css('.itempn').text
puts data.at_css('.itemcg').text
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Macintosh:nokogiri rgrush$ ruby aaa.rb
aaa.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
url = "http://sf...
                      ^
```

Any ideas?  Could it be that one of my dependencies is out of date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

most likely you have a non ASCII char in URL.

try adding

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

as first line of `aaa.rb`

so it will look like:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
```

Comment: Actually now I'm not so sure.  The error message went away but when I run the script in the terminal it just returns an empty prompt.  I believe it should be showing the results no?

Comment: @RyanGrush, i tried it and got this output: `(san jose west)
 education/teaching`

Comment: hmm I guess I need to dig around some more then.

Comment: might sound bizarre but try remove your file and create new one with the code you posted in question.

Comment: Wow that worked, thank you sir.  I guess I need to read up on char encoding too.  Why did that work if you don't mind?

Comment: sometimes files are created with bogus chars that are hard to detect/handle.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I pasted a special hyphen from a math formula into irb. Had no idea what was happening. o_O Thanks!