# UTF-8 encoding for Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding

This is a follow-up to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753601/nokogiri-syntax-error-unexpected-tidentifier-expecting-end) I asked yesterday.  I'm trying to learn standalone Ruby scripting but I'm struggling with the whole char encoding issue that was introduced to Ruby 1.9 I believe.

The poster yesterday suggested I insert the `# encoding: UTF-8` line at the top of the document, and that seemed to work for the time being.  Now I'm trying to write a simple script to echo lines into the terminal but nothing happens.  Fortunately there is no error message, but again nothing happens.

Here's an example.  This will work...

```
puts "hello"
```

and will echo `hello` in the terminal, but this ...

```
# encoding: UTF-8

puts "hello"
```

does not work.

Obviously I'm new to the complexities of char encoding, can someone explain this and what I need to do to have it work properly.

Comment: You're gonna need to give us more to go on.  I copy pasted your second script into a file and under 1.9.3p327 it does exactly what I'd expect it should do.

Comment: I'm still quite the novice here, my apologies.  I'm running ruby 1.9.3p194 btw.  Is there a command I can run that would help?

Comment: I think the problem is with your (text) editor. Maybe it is not saving the file as UTF-8. You need to set it so that it does. What text editor are you using? I may not be able to give you further advice, but others may.

Comment: Nothing I can think of :(  Maybe you've got some funky characters in there that are silently eating everything... which is a stretch, but I don't know... you could pipe the file through xxd and compare it to this https://gist.github.com/09d0026bd4ab4f322d8d  if yours is different then there's something going on.  Otherwise, something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: I'm using Espresso for Mac.  I'll try another editor and see if that helps.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom I'll give that a shot.  Been having some issues with my environment since upgrading to Mountain Lion.  I'm sure thats the problem. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can tell it looks to be a problem with Espresso.

Comment: The `# encoding` describes to ruby what encoding the file is in, you have to actually save the file in the claimed encoding, otherwise you are just lying to ruby. When saving the file, make sure you select UTF-8 **without** BOM... you also should check your file for invisible characters with a hex dump